# Calculate $E(X^3)$ given value of $E(X)$ and $E(X^2)$

Tags: probability, expectation

If I am given that for $X$, a random variable,  the value of $E(X)=3$ and $E(X^2)=9$, what is the value of $E(X^3)$? I believe I can write each as
$$E(X)=\sum xP(X=x)=3$$
$$E(X^2)=\sum x^2P(X=x)=9$$
$$E(X^3)=\sum x^3 P(X=x)$$
What should I do with the $E(X^3)$? I'm pretty sure I can't simply make it $E(X^3)=E(X) \cdot E(X^2)$.

Comment: What kind of random variable is the $X$? Is $\sum$ an infinite sum? Or what is the range for the number $x$?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In general you cannot determine $E(X^3)$ given the values of $E(X^2)$ and $E(X)$.

The point of this problem, however, is to recognize a very unusual feature about the values of $E(X)$ and $E(X^2)$, that tells you something surprising about $X$.

> We can compute $\mathrm{Var}(X) = E(X^2) - E(X)^2 = 0$, so it turns out that $X$ has no variance! Thus, we have $X=3$ almost surely (that is, $P(X=3) = 1$), and can compute $E(X^3) = E(3^3) = 27$.

Comment: Is the feature you mentioned $E(X^2)=E(X)^2$? And so, would $E(X^3)=E(X)^3=27$?

Comment: @Gyakenji: That is the feature. Do you know why it's unusual for $E(X^2) = E(X)^2$, and what that tells you about $X$? Don't guess about the value of $E(X^3)$: the important thing here is learning what this tells you about $X$! Once you know what it is, $E(X^3)$ is obvious. If you're having trouble discovering or guessing what property $X$ has, try computing other things that you *can* always compute from knowing the values of $E(X)$ and of $E(X^2)$, or consider other random variables that are simplifications of $X$.

Comment: Yeah I was thinking about that. I think that since $P(X=x)$ is the same for both $E(X)$ and $E(X^2)$, I can calculate it as a constant and I got $P(X=x)=1$. Is that what makes it unusual? Because the probability is 1?

Comment: @Gyakenji: Right; $X$ is a constant random variable! Once you know what's going on, there is actually an easy algebraic trick to prove it: $\mathrm{Var}(X) = E(X^2) - E(X)^2 = 0$

Comment: I see. Thanks a lot for clarifying this question!